# How to update shadow properties with Entity Framework Core ExecuteUpdate method?

Tags: entity-framework-core

On saving changes to the database, we want to update our shadow properties (CreatedOn & ModifiedOn) automatically. This can be done by using overriding **SaveChangesAsync** method in the DbContext class.

```cs
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var timestamp = systemClock.UtcNow.DateTime;
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseIdentifierEntity)
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.Property(nameof(BaseIdentifierEntity.CreatedOn)).CurrentValue = timestamp;
        }

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            entry.Property(nameof(BaseIdentifierEntity.ModifiedOn)).CurrentValue = timestamp;
        }
    };
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Now we want to use the **ExecuteUpdateAsync** EF code method to update records in bulk but those changes are not detected by the change tracker.

Eg.

```cs
await context.Invoices
    .Where(_ => _.Status == InvoiceStatusEnum.Draft)
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(_ => _.SetProperty(invoice => invoice.Status, InvoiceStatusEnum.Approved), cancellationToken);
```

One possible solution we're thinking about, is having a **ExecuteUpdateWithShadowPropertiesAsync** method but we don't succeed to merge the 2 expressions into one.

```cs
public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions
{
    public static Task<int> ExecuteUpdateWithShadowPropertiesAsync<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> setPropertyCalls, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where TSource : BaseIdentifierEntity
    {
        Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> setShadowPropertyCalls = _ => _.SetProperty(p => p.ModifiedOn, DateTime.UtcNow);

        // TODO: A method to combine both expressions into one expression
        var mergedPropertyCalls = Merge(setPropertyCalls, setShadowPropertyCalls);

        return source.ExecuteUpdateAsync(mergedPropertyCalls, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is documented that `ExecuteUpdate` do not use `ChangeTracker`. Try `_.SetProperty(invoice => EF.Property<DateTime>(invoice,  nameof(BaseIdentifierEntity.UpdatedOnOn), invoice => DateTime.Now)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, that is the whole point of my question. I need a generic method to update the shadow properties. In your example, I'll need to set **ModifiedOn** everywhere I use **ExecuteUpdateAsync**. I want to avoid that because the purpose of shadow properties is that you don't need to set them everywhere explicitly.

Comment: I've got it. If there will be no answers today, I'll prepare solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are two or three questions here, so let handle them separately.

1. How to update shadow properties with Entity Framework Core ExecuteUpdate method?

Shadow properties inside any EF Core query expression tree are accessed through [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-7.0) method, which is EF Core generic property accessor expression and works for both shadow and regular properties.

So if your `ModifiedOn` was a shadow property (it isn't) of type `DateTime`, it can be updated as follows:

```cs
query.ExecuteUpdateAsync(s => s
    .SetProperty(p => EF.Property<DateTime>("ModifiedOn"), DateTime.UtcNow)
    ...);
```

2. How to combine lambda expressions?

This has been covered by many answers on SO, or over internet. But basically you need to emulate "call" to one of the expressions passing the other as argument. This is achieved with either `Expression.Invoke` which is not always supported by query translators (including EF Core), or (which always works) by replacing the parameter of the "called" lambda expression with the body of the other lambda expression.

The later is achieved with custom `ExpressionVisitor`. You can find many implementations, EF Core also provides its own called `ParameterReplacingVisitor`, but I'm using my own little expression helper class, which is general and have no EF Core or other 3rd party dependencies. It is quite simple:

```cs
namespace System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceBodyParameter<T, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T, TResult>> source, Expression value)
        => source.Body.ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[0], value);

    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression source, ParameterExpression target, Expression replacement)
        => new ParameterReplacer(target, replacement).Visit(source);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly ParameterExpression target;
        readonly Expression replacement;
        public ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression target, Expression replacement)
            => (this.target, this.replacement) = (target, replacement);
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == target ? replacement : node;
    }
}
```

With that helper, the method you are looking for would be:

```
// TODO: A method to combine both expressions into one expression
var mergedPropertyCalls = Expression.Lambda<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>>(
    setShadowPropertyCalls.ReplaceBodyParameter(setPropertyCalls.Body),
    setPropertyCalls.Parameters);
```

You can go further and add a shortcut helper method specific for `SetPropertyCalls`:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> Append<TSource>(
    this Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> target,
    Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> source)
    where TSource : class
    => Expression.Lambda<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>>(
        source.ReplaceBodyParameter(target.Body), target.Parameters);
```

and then the generic method in question would be simply:

```cs
public static Task<int> ExecuteUpdateWithShadowPropertiesAsync<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> setPropertyCalls,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    where TSource : BaseIdentifierEntity
    => source.ExecuteUpdateAsync(setPropertyCalls
        .Append(s => s.SetProperty(p => p.ModifiedOn, DateTime.Now)),
        cancellationToken);
```

3. Now having the previous two questions answered, the next would be - Instead of using custom extension method, can this be done better in EF Core? Ideally on a similar fashion as the change tracker (`SaveChanges`) approach.

And the answer is yes. EF Core 7.0 along with batch updates introduced a long asked and very handy feature called [Interception to modify the LINQ expression tree](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28505) (unfortunately not documented yet). It allows you to intercept and modify LINQ query expression tree before EF Core. In this case, it could be used to add more update properties to `ExecuteUpdate` query.

In order to utilize it, we first define interceptor class

```cs
#nullable disable

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

internal class ExecuteUpdateInterceptor : IQueryExpressionInterceptor
{
    List<(Type Type, Delegate Calls, Func<IEntityType, bool> Filter)> items = new();

    public ExecuteUpdateInterceptor Add<TSource>(
        Func<Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>>> source,
        Func<IEntityType, bool> filter = null)
    {
        items.Add((typeof(TSource), source, filter));
        return this;
    }

    Expression IQueryExpressionInterceptor.QueryCompilationStarting(
        Expression queryExpression, QueryExpressionEventData eventData)
    {
        if (queryExpression is MethodCallExpression call &&
            call.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(RelationalQueryableExtensions) &&
            call.Method.Name == nameof(RelationalQueryableExtensions.ExecuteUpdate))
        {
            var setPropertyCalls = (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)call.Arguments[1]).Operand;
            var body = setPropertyCalls.Body;
            var parameter = setPropertyCalls.Parameters[0];
            var targetType = eventData.Context?.Model.FindEntityType(parameter.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
            if (targetType != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    if (!item.Type.IsAssignableFrom(targetType.ClrType)) continue;
                    if (item.Filter != null && !item.Filter(targetType)) continue;
                    var calls = (LambdaExpression)item.Calls.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
                        .MakeGenericMethod(targetType.ClrType)
                        .Invoke(null, null);
                    body = calls.Body.ReplaceParameter(calls.Parameters[0], body);
                }
                if (body != setPropertyCalls.Body)
                    return call.Update(call.Object, new[] { call.Arguments[0], Expression.Lambda(body, parameter) });
            }
        }
        return queryExpression;
    }
}
```

This requires a bit more knowledge of expressions, so you can just use it as is. Basically what it does is intercepting the `ExecuteUpdate` "calls" and appending additional `SetProperty` "calls" based on statically configured rules and filters.

The only remaining is to create, configure and add the interceptor inside your `OnConfigure` override:

```cs
optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new ExecuteUpdateInterceptor()
    //.Add(...)
    //.Add(...)
);
```

The configuration is based on delegates, with only **limitation/requirement** the `SetPropertyCalls` generic `Func` to be a **real generic method** and not anonymous delegate (I haven't found a way to make it easy for use and at the same time being anonymous).

So here are some usages:

- property of a base class (your case):

```cs
optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new ExecuteUpdateInterceptor()
    .Add(SetModifiedOn<BaseIdentifierEntity>)
);

static Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> SetModifiedOn<TSource>()
    where TSource : BaseIdentifierEntity
    => s => s.SetProperty(p => p.ModifiedOn, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

- entity property with specific name and type (shadow or regular). Uses presence of the property as a filter. Also works in your case.

```cs
const string ModifiedOn = nameof(ModifiedOn);

optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new ExecuteUpdateInterceptor()
    .Add(SetModifiedOn<object>, t => t.FindProperty(ModifiedOn) is { } p && p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime))
);

static Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> SetModifiedOn<TSource>()
    where TSource : class
    => s => s.SetProperty(p => EF.Property<DateTime>(p,ModifiedOn), DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Note: The `SetPropertyCalls` func must be generic, to allow binding it to the actual source type from the query.

Also, I haven't mentioned it explicitly till now, but with the last approach, you just use a standard `ExecuteUpdate` or `ExecuteUpdateAsync` methods, and the interceptor adds the cofigured additional `SetProperty` expressions.

Comment: I didn't know about the interceptors in EF Core 7.0 so I thought it wasn't possible but this is of course the way to go. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to set a non-clr column this way? My Auditable base class has some context info which is an object translated into jsonb (postgres). So I've tried to add a second SetProperty into your "property of a base class (your case)" example like this `s => s.SetProperty(p => p.DateUpdated, DateTime.UtcNow).SetProperty(p => p.BrowserInfo, browserInfo);` but it causes The following lambda argument to 'SetProperty' does not represent a valid value: '<>c__DisplayClass0_0<User>.browserInfo'. exception.

Answer (score 1):

The following extension updates shadow property with other fields:

```cs
public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions
{
    public static Task<int> ExecuteUpdateWithShadowPropertiesAsync<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
        Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> setPropertyCalls, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) 
        where TSource : class
    {
        Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> setShadowPropertyCalls =
            x => x.SetProperty(p => EF.Property<DateTime>(p, "ModifiedOn"), p => DateTime.UtcNow);

        var mergedPropertyCalls = Merge(setPropertyCalls, setShadowPropertyCalls);

        return source.ExecuteUpdateAsync(mergedPropertyCalls, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }

    static Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> Merge<TSource>(
        Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> setPropertyCalls,
        Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> additional)
    {
        var newBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(additional.Parameters[0], setPropertyCalls.Body, additional.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>>(newBody,
            setPropertyCalls.Parameters);
    }
}
```